# CakePHP - MVC Model Associations - How can I structure this data model?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model, model-associations

quick question that I have been stuck with since hours:

For my cakePHP website project (using version 2.0) I have 2 Models. They are a bit obscure so I'll translate the model to the standard blog post models.

So I have a "Posts" model and for those many "Categories".

```
class Post
$belongsTo = 'Category'

class Category
$hasMany = 'Post'
```

So far so good. Now I want every category to have exactly one (mandatory) 'main post'.

How would I associate that?

- Another 'MainPost' Model? That seems redundant as it would have the same content as the posts.
- A boolean 'is_main' column in the posts? Doesn't seem right since only one post of each category is allowed to be "main".
- A 'mainpost_id' column in the categories? Sounds good but "$belongsTo" is the only association that allows the foreign key to be in the current class. And to say that a Category belongsTo Post when the opposite is also true seems wrong to me. Also belongsTo is a many-to-one association and what I want is kind of a one-to-one association.

Please help me, [insert name]. You're my only hope. ;)

Edit: I guess it would be great if there was a way to have a "hasOne" relationship but have the foreign key in the same class that $hasOne X and not in the other as is standard.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `mainpost`? A quick solution would be to add extra fields to the category table for this purpose, and be done with it providing your requirements aren't likely to change (kind of like WordPress's category description?)

Comment: Hey Ross, no it's not like the description. The purpose for it is to have a kind of poster child that gets displayed when no other data is given. It is exactly the same like every other post, just that it is marked as the ... let's say "standard" for a specific category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
[ categories ]
id
name
mainpost_id

[ posts ]
id
category_id
title
text
```

- Category **hasMany** Post
- Post **belongsTo** Category
- Category **hasOne** MainPost ([see code](https://gist.github.com/1488116))

Comment: It would be perfect if I could get this to work. The only problem I am running into when trying this is that upon calling `$this->Category->find();` in the CategoriesController it returns `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post.mainpost_id' in 'on clause'` because it expects the "mainpost_id" to be in the Posts model and not in the Categories model

Comment: Well, obvious solution would be to just use `Category belongsTo MainPost` and keep the rest from your gist. Still sounds wrong to say it but it does what it should for now. Sooo ... thanks Tiu :) Still if someone can think of a better alternative please post it here!

Answer (score 0):

i think you use hasAndBelongsToMany relationship....see more details at this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: hasAndBelongsToMany models a many-to-many relationship, which isn't really what the OP is describing.

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem to me that in that case posts really have many categories and the other way around. post has one category, each category has one main post. Or is there something I am not seeing here?